# cannot convert from bufferedreader to string

Tags: java, android, eclipse, load, assets

i want to load file from assets folder and use a string at stopword procces, this ini my code but i get error "cannot convert from bufferedreader to string"

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v.getId()==R.id.button6){

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("Preposisi.txt"), "UTF-8")); 

            // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading 
            String mLine = reader.readLine();
            while (mLine != null) {
               //process line

               mLine = reader.readLine(); 
            }

            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //log the exception
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreposisiRemoval.class);
        String test = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7)).getText().toString();
        String[] preposisi = {text}; "GET ERROR IN THIS LINE"
        StringBuilder resultFilter = new StringBuilder();

        Scanner fip1 = new Scanner(test);
            while (fip1.hasNext()){
                    int flag = 1;
                    String s1 = fip1.next();
                    for (int i = 0;i<preposisi.length; i++){
                        if (s1.equals(preposisi[i])){
                            flag=0;
                        }
                        }   
                        if(flag!=0){
                            System.out.println(s1);
                            resultFilter.append(s1+'\n');
                        }

                        Intent intent2 = getIntent();
                                String count = intent2.getStringExtra("result2");

                    intent.putExtra("resultFilter", resultFilter.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("count", count);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
        }
}
```

i get error in the line String preposisi = {test}

Comment: in which line you are converting from bufferedreader to string

Comment: What do you want to do in the line `String[] preposisi = {text};`?

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
```

AND

```
String test = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7)).getText().toString();
String[] preposisi = {text}; "GET ERROR IN THIS LINE";
```

"test" or "text"???

Comment: text(this is file load from asset folder)

Comment: text is an instance of StringBuilder and you are trying to cast to String. String[] preposisi = {test}; I think so

Comment: i get error "cannot convert from bufferedreader to string" if use String[] preposisi = {test};

Answer (score 0):

`text` is a `StringBuilder` which is not compatible with a `String` array . Did you mean

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
String[] preposisi = {text.toString()};
```

or simply

```
String[] preposisi = { test };
```

?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your read loop:

   ```
   String mLine = reader.readLine();
   while (mLine != null) {
      mLine = reader.readLine(); 
      text.append(mLine);  //You missed this line
   }
   ```

   Otherwise your StringBuilder will always be empty.